# Highcharts - programmatically draw a line or graphic between two related points

Tags: highcharts

I often have charts that require a design element like a curly brace to call attention to call attention to a range or comparison in a graph, such as the y-difference in two points at the end of a graph.

My first take is that this would be a job for Highcharts `Renderer` API. Load the graph, and run a callback that adds an image (or line, shape, whatever) via `chart.renderer.image(...)`  or similar.

That's the approach I have started down, but I'm just missing how to get the coordinates for chart data points within the callback. Here's a working [codepen](http://codepen.io/ericpedia/pen/bdmop) of the code below. What doesn't work is that there's no logic to give it proper placement on the canvas (suppose I want the bracket to go from the final top point to the final bottom point)

```
$('#container').highcharts({
    data: { table: document.getElementById('datatable') },
    chart: { type: 'line' }, 
    title: { text: 'Data extracted from a HTML table in the page'
    }
}, function(chart){

  var img = 'http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/4b/Curly_bracket_right.svg/30px-Curly_bracket_right.svg.png';

  // How can I populate these values?
  var x = 0; // should programmatically get x-position of last point
  var y = 0; // should programmatically get y-position of last point
  var h = 100; // should programmatically get distance between y-position of top and bottom points
  var w = 50;

  chart.renderer.image( img, x, y, w, h ).add();
});
```

Is there a straightforward way to populate those values? Or is there a better way to do this entirely?

Comment: So you would like to have two points and between them draw shape / image or something different?

Comment: @SebastianBochan Yes, using two points from an existing graph. Also, I want to grab the coordinates of the points in a programmatic way, as opposed to specifying hard-coding coordinates in the callback function (because I want to use this on many graphs).

Comment: Each point has a parameter in graphic/element object. I advice to use console.log() of points and take look at the structure and parametesr like coordinates. In combination with toPixels/toValue (described below) you should achieve your goal.

Answer (score 1):

to get the position you want you can use few methods provided by highcharts in their API.

methods like toPixels(), toValue() will help you to alter your required position as per the chart demogrphics.

please refer their api

toPixels() : http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Axis.toPixels()

toValue() : http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Axis.toValue()

hope using this will solve your requirement of positioning